# How to best populate 2 different objects, of an almost identical class, from 2 different DLLs without having to maintain two different objects?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have 2 classes with the same name (let's call it ClassX), under the same hierarchy, in 2 separate DLLs. Both of these DLLs are from a third-party. Dll1.ClassX and Dll2.ClassX are also under the same namespace in both of these DLLs. Let the DLLs be Dll1 and Dll2. Now, let's consider two objects, objA and objB, of the same class. My application has to either create only objA or only objB or both depending on certain conditions that we get back from the DB. I use external aliases to resolve the ambiguity in the class references in my application. Now comes the situation/s.

Use case 1 or 2 (creating a single object, either objA or objB) is easy. The tricky part is when I have to create both objA and objB in my application. Since only certain properties of objA and objB vary, the brute force way would be to create 2 different objects and then populate them, at the same time, as the code flows through my application. However, this would mean I'd have to re-write most of the object creation code to accommodate for the "extra" object now. Sounds tedious to me. I want to know if there's a better way of doing this.

Comment: try to use reflection API

Comment: @Thakur : Can you elaborate a little more on that ?

Comment: To create a copy of object (clone it) typical approach is to serialize existing and deserialize new one. You can also use same approach, e.g. json + custom binder will do.

Comment: @Sinatr : The Dll2 object version objB is backward compatible but i.e. let's say I serialize objA to a.xml and then deserialize it back from a.xml to objB then that works. however, not all the properties get populated appropriately. I know this can be corrected on a case-by-case basis but that should be my last resort. Is there anything else I can try ? Secondly, some of the method signatures of objB are different from that of objA's. So, that's also something that I have to take into account.

Comment: *"however, not all the properties get populated appropriately"* - usually their default value should be appropriate (if it's missing in xml). If there is a logic behind, then you can't avoid running it. Still deserialization will save you from manual assignment. *"some of the method signatures of objB are different"* - methods signatures has nothing to do with the state (properties and fields values), can you elaborate how is that a problem? It would be the best if you give a brief code example how those objects looks like and how do you solve the problem now. Other solution may not exists.

Comment: Consider this. 
Dll1.classA 
{ 
 void ABC(int a, string s); 
 public string Name; 
}

Dll2.classA 
{ 
 void ABC(int a, string s, bool b); 
 public string SomethingElse; 
}

So, in my application, let's say there is a code snippet like this :

class MyAppClass
{
 public void DoSomething()
 {
  //Current code
  Dll1.classA ca = new Dll1.classA();
  ca.ABC(1,"abc");

  //New DLL - should work fine
  Dll1.classB cb = new Dll1.classB();
  cb.ABC(1,"abc", false);

  //I don't want to "ideally" create BOTH ca and cb above. Ideally, I want to just use one object 
  
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

Unify them using a new common interface and two adapter classes that implement the interface using an owned instance of the appropriate "real" class.

Comment: Sure, will give it a shot. Thanks !